# CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync

Tags: gsutil

After using gsutil for more than 1 year I suddenly have this error:

```
.....
At destination listing 8350000...
At destination listing 8360000...
CommandException: Caught non-retryable exception - aborting rsync
.....
```

I tried to locate the files with this sync problem but I am not able to do so. Is there a "skip error" option of is there a way I can have gsutil more verbose?

My command line is like this:

```
gsutil -V -m rsync -d -r -U -P -C -e -x  -x 'Download/*' /opt/ gs://mybucket1/kraanloos/
```

---

```
I have created a script to split the problem. This gives me more info for a solution


!#/bin/bash
array=(
3ware
AirTime
Amsterdam
BigBag
Download
guide
home
Install
Holding
Multimedia
newsite
Overig
Trak-r
)


for i in "${array[@]}"
do
    echo Processing : $i
    PROCESS="/usr/bin/gsutil -m rsync -d -r -U -P -C -e -x 'Backup/*' /opt/$i/ gs://mybucket1/kraanloos/$i/"
    echo $PROCESS
    $PROCESS
    echo ""
    echo ""
done
```

Comment: Improve formatting.

Answer (score 3):

I've been struggling with the same problem the last few days.  One way to make it super verbose is to put the `-D` flag before the `rsync` argument, as in:
`gsutil -D rsync ...`

By doing that, I found that my problem is due to having `#` characters in filenames, as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28582964/gsutil-rsync-gives-a-400-non-retryable-exception-on-s3-bucket).

Answer (score 1):

In my case, it was because of a broken link to a directory.

As [blambert said](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54032983/766330), use the `-D` option to see exactly what file causes the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had struggled with this problem as well. I figured it out now.
you need to re-authenticate your Google Cloud SDK Shell and set a target project again.
It seems like rsync will not show the correct error message.

try cp instead, it will guide you to authentic and set the correct primary project

```
gsutil cp OBJECT_LOCATION gs://DESTINATION_BUCKET_NAME/
```

after that, your gsutil rsync should run fine.